# Find out if loaded view is not preview mode in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I need to find out if opened tab is preview or not,  I've written this:

```
class Plugini(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  def on_load(self, view):

     sublime.message_dialog("file opened")
```

but it keeps showing dialog if file opened in preview mode, then I've tried this:

```
class Plugini(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  def on_load(self, view):
     for v in sublime.active_window().views():
        if v.id() == view.id():
           sublime.message_dialog("found this new view in views") 

     sublime.message_dialog("file opened")
```

but It find new preview tab in views, so is there any way to know view is in `preview` mode?

Maybe another event exist (something like `on_open`) to catch new view (not in preview mode).

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible in all cases, although it has been [**requested**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/is-view-transient-preview-method/3247). Check out [**bizoo's post**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/st3-detecting-preview-window-in-api/11643/4) & [**FichteFoll's post**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-3031/9925/13) on the issue. It looks like their solutions work in some cases, but not all. I tried bizoo's method on transient views that were opened by the sidebar & it did not work.

Comment: Thanks @Enteleform, actually bizoo's post helped me in some way, I used it to skip my plugin functionality in that case, It's not what I want, but this will prevent weird results